# EVT_BUTTON triggers on frame load

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

My app has 2 frames. I can freely go from first to second by pressing the button on the first frame. For some reason when I load 2nd frame, EVT_BUTTON, that I bind to one of its buttons triggers. To make matter worse it doesn't trigger when I click it in 2nd frame. I'm new to python and wx library, but so far it was pretty straight forward, now I'm kinda stuck.

```
class ItemInfo(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, item, *args):
        super(ItemInfo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.Centre()
        # self.Size = wx.Size(500, 900)
        self.current_item = self.find_current_item(item)

        #I skipped several boxsizers in this snipped

        test_button = wx.Button(self, label="Test")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.show_current_item_stats(), test_button)
        button_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        button_sizer.Add(test_button, wx.ID_ANY, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.main_sizer.Add(button_sizer, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.main_sizer)


     def show_current_item_stats(self):
        self.current_item.stat_bonuses["Strength"] += 510
        self.current_item_strength_bonus.SetLabel(f"Strength: {self.current_item.stat_bonuses['Strength']}")
'''
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you clarify your issue? Also, edit yor question and add the code for the binded function `show_current_item_stats()`

Comment: I found answer, instead of just binding handler to an event,  I call the function by adding () to function name +)

Comment: Then post the solution as an answer. And accept it

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I accidentally called function by adding () to it, instead of just binding it. Silly me +)